# Isotope folded (elements overlap)

Tags: jquery, filter, jquery-isotope, overlap, fold

I have been reading stack overflow for a solution but can't find it.

[image]
(*full size image at https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0hd0.png*)

When I load the page it looks like that

Here is the site (beta)

http://e-gimnazija.hostoi.com/test/site/index.html

If you press ***all*** it unfolds, maybe I can solve it if it auto unfolds at the start

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The problem is that when you run `.isotope` the images are not yet loaded, so the plugin cannot calculate their size..

You have some different options to choose from

1. Start isotope after the images have loaded.. `$(window).load(function(){/*init plugin here*/})`
2. Use the ***imagesLoaded plugin***: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/help.html#imagesloaded_plugin
3. call [`reLayout`](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/methods.html#relayout) once the images are loaded `$(window).load(function(){$('#thumbs').isotope('reLayout');});`
4. if the `li` elements are fixed size, then give them dimensions through CSS, and `isotope` will pick them up..

Comment: Very helpful. The imagesLoaded method is not available in isotop v2 beta but the $(window).load() option works flawless.

Comment: @mrleone see http://isotope.metafizzy.co/beta/appendix.html#imagesloaded for v2 `imagesLoaded`

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli I didn't found it when I looked for it. Thanks!

Comment: How can I use the "$(window).load..." function in coffeescript?

Comment: @Luc that would be `$(window).load -> /*init plugin here*/`

Comment: I eventually went for the imagesLoaded plugin, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it with jquery:

```
<script type='text/javascript' >
    $(window).load(function() {
        $.getScript('/js/jquery.isotope.min.js', function() { });
    });
</script>
```

This waits for the whole page to be loaded, then loads the isotope script last.  Below, I have a more complete solution, using a "working" notification and a spinner until everything gets loaded.  The spinner is from font-awesome icons...

```
<div class="container wrapper">
    <div class="inner_content">
        <div class='working' >
            <h2>working... <i class="icon-spinner icon-spin icon-large"></i></h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type='text/javascript' >
    $(window).load(function() {
        $.getScript('/js/jquery.isotope.min.js', function() {
            $('.working').fadeOut();
        });
    });
</script>
```

You can see my working example at:  http://ericavhay.com/painting/portfolio

Answer (score 0):

While we use

```js
jQuery(window).load(function($){});
```

function it's throwing an `Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function`

Instead of you can use:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
setTimeout(function(){ 
        //Isotope Code place here 
     }, 3000);
});
```

It's working fine.